# Implementing NSCoding for NSKeyedArchiver and memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I have a custom object that I am using NSKeyedArchiver to convert to NSData so my custom object implements the NSCoding protocol. But when I run the Instruments tool, it tells me that my initWithCoder method has a number of leaked NSCFString objects inside initWithCoder.

What is the correct way to implement the NSCoding protocol?

My class:

```
@interface EventProfile : NSObject <NSCoding>
    NSString *eventTitle;   
    NSString *groupName;                                
@end
@implementation EventProfile

// NSCoding methods
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        eventTitle = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"eventTitle"] retain];
        groupName = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"groupName"] retain];
    }

    return self;
}
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.eventTitle forKey:@"eventTitle"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.groupName forKey:@"groupName"];  
}
// Memory management
- (void)dealloc
{           
    [eventTitle release];
    [groupName release];

    [super dealloc];
}    

@end
```

Comment: What are the definitions of the `eventTitle` and `groupName` properties? If they are `copy`, things look Ok to me. But if they are accidentally `assign` you might have a problem there. Could you also test run the code with `self.eventTitle` and `self.groupName` in the `initWithCoder:` method? Apart from that it might be that the leak is at the place that uses the `EventTitle` class at a different place.

Comment: Yes your interface shows no property definitions but you are using `self.eventTitle` and `self.groupName` inside `encodeWithCoder:` ??

Answer (score 1):

To implement encodeWithCoder: you should go through all of the essential properties of your object and use the various methods on NSCoder to encode them. For object properties, just use encodeObject:forKey:. The key can just be a short string that describes the property being encoded:

```
class Book: NSObject, NSCoding {
var title: String
var author: String
var pageCount: Int
var categories: [String]
var available: Bool

// Memberwise initializer
init(title: String, author: String, pageCount: Int, categories: [String], available: Bool) {
    self.title = title
    self.author = author
    self.pageCount = pageCount
    self.categories = categories
    self.available = available
}

// MARK: NSCoding

required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let title = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as? String,
        let author = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("author") as? String,
        let categories = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("categories") as? [String]
        else { return nil }

    self.init(
        title: title,
        author: author,
        pageCount: decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("pageCount"),
        categories: categories,
        available: decoder.decodeBoolForKey("available")
    )
}

func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(self.title, forKey: "title")
    coder.encodeObject(self.author, forKey: "author")
    coder.encodeInt(Int32(self.pageCount), forKey: "pageCount")
    coder.encodeObject(self.categories, forKey: "categories")
    coder.encodeBool(self.available, forKey: "available")
}
```

}

As you can see, NSCoding is mostly boilerplate. Each property is encoded or decoded as an object or type, using the name of the property of as the key each time. (Some developers prefer to define NSString * constants for each keypath, but this is usually unnecessary).